# Different expectations for scanf, via push and pop

Tags: c, stack, queue, push, scanf

Writing this program in C. Implementing at queue using two stacks (problem 3.5 in CTCI).

I want to allow the user to enter "push {integer}" or "pop." I'm using `scanf("%s %d", op, &data);`

However, this leads to inconsistent behavior in the program, where user input "push {integer}" works fine, but user input "pop" results in delayed program execution. It seems that `scanf("%s %d", op, &data);` waits for some input to place into &data, but I want it to just accept "pop" without any data.

Code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "../Chapter-2/linkedlist.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char op[10];
    int data;
    struct node *pushStack = NULL;
    struct node *popStack = NULL;

    printf("Usage: \"push\" some_int ||OR|| \"pop\"\n");
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%s %d", op, &data);
        if(strncmp(op, "push", 4) == 0)
        {
            if(pushStack == NULL)
            {
                if(popStack != NULL) //we were popping from the "queue" so we need to switch to pushing mode
                {
                    while(popStack != NULL) //transfer all from popstack to pushstack
                    {
                        push(&pushStack, pop(&popStack));
                    }
                }
            }
            push(&pushStack, data);
        } else if(strncmp(op, "pop", 3) == 0)
        {
            if(popStack == NULL)
            {
                if(pushStack != NULL) //we were pushing to "queue" so we need to switch to pop mode
                {
                    while(pushStack != NULL) // transfer all from pushStack to popStack
                    {
                        push(&popStack, pop(&pushStack));
                    }
                }
            }
            if(popStack == NULL) //could still be null if there was nothing to transfer from pushstack
                printf("Queue is empty. You have nothing to pop.\n");
            else
                printf("Popped queue: %d\n", pop(&popStack));
        } else {
            printf("Invalid usage.\n");
            printf("Usage: \"push\" some_int ||OR|| \"pop\"\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you acquire the input with `fgets`. Then apply `sscanf` and check the return value (number of converted fields, an *essential* test under **all** circumstances). If the "pop" was received, without the second argument, you can dump the input string more easily than you can ignore unsatisfied `scanf` format fields, which are persistent. Unlike `scanf` the string function `sscanf` does not wait for more information.

Comment: Aside: standard library headers should be included with `#include <stdio.h>` not as `#include "stdio.h"`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to split the `scanf` into two calls dependent on the command. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char op[10];
    int data;
    int t = 3;
    int res;

    printf("Usage: \"push\" some_int ||OR|| \"pop\"\n");
    while(t)
    {
        res = scanf("%9s", op);    // Read the command
        if (res == EOF) exit(1);

        if(strncmp(op, "push", 4) == 0)
        {
            do
            {
                res = scanf("%d", &data);  // Read data only when command is push
                if (res == EOF) exit(1);
                if (res != 1) 
                    while ( (res = getchar()) != '\n' && res != EOF ); // Flush stdin
             } while (res != 1);
                   
             printf("%s %d\n", op, data);
        } 
        else if(strncmp(op, "pop", 3) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", op);
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Invalid usage.\n");
            printf("Usage: \"push\" some_int ||OR|| \"pop\"\n");
        }
        --t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Input

```
push 7
pop
push 42
```

> Output

```
Usage: "push" some_int ||OR|| "pop"
push 7
pop
push 42
```

BTW:

> Always check the return value of scanf
>
> Never do scanf(%s ....

As alternative to `scanf` you could use `fgets`. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char op[10];
    int data;
    int t = 3;

    printf("Usage: \"push\" some_int ||OR|| \"pop\"\n");
    while(t)
    {
        if (fgets(op, 10, stdin) == NULL) exit(1);

        if(sscanf(op, "push %d", &data) == 1)
        {
            printf("push %d\n", data);
        }
        else if(strncmp(op, "pop", 3) == 0)
        {
            printf("pop\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid usage.\n");
            printf("Usage: \"push\" some_int ||OR|| \"pop\"\n");
        }
        --t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With `while` in `while(1 != scanf("%9s", op));` looks like a potential infinite loop should `stdin` get closed.  What is the use of `while`?

Comment: @chux - well... the use of `while` was to make sure that `op` was initialized before use. But that's not really need for format `%9s` (but is for format `%d`). Also the missing EOF check makes the code a bit sloppy. Thanks for pointing that out. I've tried to improve the code.